# Two dropdown list and save in database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu, insert

In that project, I want to create two drop down lists(category, item). If I select one of the category named car, then item drop down list should have: Honda, Volvo, Nissan.

If I select one of the category named phone, then item drop down list should have: iPhone, Samsung, Nokia.

HTML:

```
    <select id="cat">
        <option val="car">car</option>
        <option val="phone">phone</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item">

    </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if(cat=='car'){
        cars.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option value="cars[]">'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='phone'){
        phones.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append('<option value="phones[]">'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

And then in PHP:

```
$cat=$_request['cat'];
$phones=$_request['phones'];
```

I want to save first dropdown(cat) and second dropdown(item) in database with PHP, but Error. 
Help me to save this two dropdown in database.

Comment: what kind of error? what column type has your database for these fields?

Comment: the value of second dropdown( value="phones[]" or value="cars[]") Not known ! the array Not known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - your select did not had any name = and your values where totally wrong

```
<select name="cat[]" id="cat">
    <option val="car">car</option>
    <option val="phone">phone</option>
</select>

<select name="item[]" id="item">

</select>



cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

  $('#cat').change(function(){
    populateSelect();
  });

});


function populateSelect(){
  cat=$('#cat').val();
  $('#item').html('');


  if(cat=='car'){
      cars.forEach(function(t) { 
          $('#item').append('<option value="cars'+t+'">'+t+'</option>');
    });
}

if(cat=='phone'){
    phones.forEach(function(t) {
        $('#item').append('<option value="'+t+'">'+t+'</option>');
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to define variables and try

```
var cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
var phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) To retrieve values from the `selects` with PHP they need to be inside a `form` that the user will submit to a page that will process the data. The `selects` also need a `name` attribute for this.

2.) `<option val=` is incorrect. It should be `<option value=`. Note that if you leave out the value attribute, the option itself will be the value.

3.)  `$_request` is case sensitive and needs to be capitalized: `$_REQUEST`

Assuming you will process the data on a page called `processor.php`, you can try something like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="POST">
    <select id="cat" name="cat">
        <option value="car">car</option>
        <option value="phone">phone</option>
    </select>

    <select id="item" name="item">

    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if(cat=='car'){
        cars.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append("<option value='"+t+"'>"+t+"</option>");
        });
    }

    if(cat=='phone'){
        phones.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append("<option value='"+t+"'>"+t+"</option>");
        });
    }

}
```

PHP: (In this example, the form is submitted to an example page `processor.php`)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    // You now have the user selections saved in the above variables and
    // can proceed with inserting them into the database...
    // ... use mysqli or pdo to connect to and query the db   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <form action="http://localhost/rat.html.php" method="POST">
           <select name="car" id="car">
                <option value="car">Car</option>
                <option value="phone">Phone</option>
           </select>

           <select name="items" id="items">
           </select>

           <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
      </form>

     <script type="text/javascript" >
        var cars=["Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche"]
        var phones=['Samsung','Nokia','Iphone']

        var ele = document.getElementById('car');

        ele.onchange = function(){addItem(this.value,"items")}

        function addItem(item,id){
            var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        ele.innerHTML = "";

        var elements = (item=="car")?cars : phones;         


        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            ele.innerHTML += "<option value="+elements[i]+">"+elements[i]+" </option>"
                }   
        }
    </script>

    //rat.html.php

    <?php
    $name = $_POST['car'];
    $it = $_POST['items'];
    echo($name);
    echo($it);

    ?>
```